# Pass Additional Variable in Option Selected form

Tags: php, forms

I have a loop that creates options in a drop down form.

How can I pass the variable `$objectID[$i]` from the loop where `$i` consistent with the selected value `$i`

```
echo '<form action="#" method="post"><select name="Restaurant">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($restaurants); $i++){
    $name[$i]  = $restaurants[$i]->get("Name");
    $city[$i]  = $restaurants[$i]->get("City");
    $objectID[$i] = $restaurants[$i]->getObjectID();
    //echo '<input type="hidden" name="passRestaurant" value="' . $name[$i]. '" />'; // tried this, but it just messes up the format of the drop down
    echo "<option>{$name[$i]} -" . " {$city[$i]}</option>";
}
echo '</select><br><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>';
}
```

This prints the value that was selected, but I also want to print the `$objectID[$i]` at the same `$i` value:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['Restaurant'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you just put `$objectID[$i]` in

```
echo "<option value=\"{$objectID[$i]}\">{$name[$i]} - {$city[$i]}</option>";
```

so you can get all the properties of `Restaurant` with `$objectID`

Comment: I just realized the same thing. Thanks for the answer!